# How to select the id

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem on selecting an id on div. I use a while loop on my div.
So i'am creating a unique ID using the id row on my sql. My question is, is it possible to select the id using Javascript? I use bootstrap modal to update my information details (i dont actually know how to ask this question because my english is poor).

example:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
    <div id="'details-'<?php echo $row['Room_ID'];?>">
    //code
    </div>
}
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("YOUR_ID")`?

Comment: add a class to all your div's created with that pattern, and then just get the id of the element with split var id=element.split('-')[1] //your id.

Answer (score 2):

To fix your Php code:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
   echo "<div id='details-" . $row['Room_ID'] ."'>";
       // CODE
   echo "</div>";
}
```

The problem you got in the id, where you stopped the value by `'` already, so the result was something like:

`<div id='details-'28>//Code</div>` and fixed to `<div id='details-28'>//Code</div>`

and to select the ID with pure JavaScript use `document.getElementById( ID )`

If you are not sure of the ID and you just wanna select all items, add a class to the item and select them all by `document.getElementsByClassName`

So to select all your stuff by javascript:

1) Add into your PHP code class called "details"
2) Create a javascript to select all items with the class name "details"
3) Do a foreach loop for the selected items and split them by "-" to devide the "details" from the actual ID
4) Do whatever you want now with the ID

Practical showcase:

Php:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
   echo "<div class='details' id='details-" . $row['Room_ID'] ."'>";
       // CODE
   echo "</div>";
}
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
var itemDetails = document.getElementsByClassName("details");

for(var i = 0; i < itemDetails.length; i ++) {
    var ID = itemDetails[i].getAttribute("id").split("-")[1]; 
    // Now you got the ID stored in the variable ID
</script>
```

[Here you got an example on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xk80ppt8/1/)

Answer (score 0):

As for as my understanding from your code, you are want to create a div with id details from your database. For that you should correct your code as given blew

`<?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
        echo "<div id='details-'". $row['Room_ID'];">";
        //code
        echo "</div>";
    }
?>`

If it is problem to select it and perform some manipulations using jQuery/javascript you may consult the official API documentation at 
[This link](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)